# Shoes hangs on Net::FTP put

Tags: ruby, file-upload, shoes, net-ftp

So I wrote the following piece of code:

```
Shoes.app(:title=> "Humax Uploader", :width=>400, :height=>400) {
    background rgb(240, 250, 208)
    stack(margin:10) {
        title "Humax Uploader"
        server = '[ip]'
        user = '[user]'
        pass = '[pass]'
        require 'net/ftp'
        @feedback = para "Find a file:"
        flow do
            @filename = edit_line :width => 150
            para ' '
            button 'Browse...' do
                @filename.text = ask_open_file
            end
        end

        file_list = ['My Music','My Photo','My Video']
        list_box :items => file_list do |list|
                Net::FTP.open(server, user, pass) { |ftp|
                    usize = 0
                    fsize = File.size(@filename.text)
                    ftp.putbinaryfile(@filename.text,"/mnt/hd2/" + list.text + "/" + File.basename(@filename.text),1024) { |block|  
                        usize += block.size
                        @p.fraction = fsize/usize
                    }
                    @file_select.text = "File uploaded!"
                    ftp.close
                }
            end
        @p = progress :width => 360
        @file_select = para " "
    }
}
```

Basically, what it does is allowing a user to select a file, the folder it should go into and then, the program should upload it.

This happens correctly: Stuff uploads fine, but unfortunately: The program window hangs during upload. Why is this happening (do you experience the same problems?) and how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Note that I am running this script on Windows and have not yet 'build' to executable yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it hang forever or just until the file has been uploaded? In either case I think this is a scheduling problem.

You might want to consider running the upload [in a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958662/shoes-and-heavy-operation-in-separate-thread) ([this link](http://www.randomhacks.net/articles/2009/05/08/chat-client-ruby-amqp-eventmachine-shoes) might also be of use) or perhaps running it as a separate process and using some sort of socket or file for inter-process communication.

Comment: It hangs until the file has been uploaded: Then the process bar fills and everything is fine. Unfortunately, just 'adding' a thread didn't work for me. Will now check out that second link!

Comment: YOUR SECOND LINK DID IT! One has to make a new thread (outside the app) and process the stuff in there. Now I need to find out how to make it update the progress bar :P